# How to search array for course

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am having an issue with searching an array for a course;
Here are the parameters:
This method will allow a student to search for a course name from their existing schedule. 
Use a WHILE loop that will stop when one of two conditions is true:  either the course is found OR you have reached the last course in the schedule and did not have a match. 
If the course is found then print out the course name and number of credits. 
If the course is not found then print out a message stating the course is not listed on the student's schedule. 
Only search through existing courses.  If the array is not full and you search the entire array your program will have a run-time error.

Here is my code so far, thank you in advance:

```
public class Student {
 //Instance Data
 String studentName;
 String studentID;
 String streetAddress;
 String city;
 String state;
 String zipCode;
 String major;

 int totalCredits;
 final int MAX_CREDITS = 18;
 final int SIZE = 6;
 String[] schedule = new String[SIZE];
 int courseNumber = 0;

 //Create Constructor:
 //Initializes the student data at instantiation time.
 //-------------------------------------------------------
 //  Sets up the student's information.
 //-------------------------------------------------------
 public Student(String name, String id, String address, String cityName, String stateName, String zip, String area) {
   studentName = name;
   studentID = id;
   streetAddress = address;
   city = cityName;
   state = stateName;
   zipCode = zip;
   major = area;
  } //end Student Constructor

 //Method to Return student information as string:
 //-------------------------------------------------------
 //  Returns the student information as a formatted string.
 //-------------------------------------------------------
 public String toString() {
   String studentInfo;

   studentInfo = "Name:\t\t\t" + studentName + "\n" + "ID:\t\t\t" + studentID + "\n" + "Address:\t\t" + streetAddress + "\n" + "City:\t\t\t" + city + "\n" + "State:\t\t\t" + state + "\n" + "Zip Code:\t\t" + zipCode + "\n" + "Major:\t\t\t" + major + "\n";

   return studentInfo;
  } // end toString


 //Method to determine if maximum allowed credits have been exceeded
 //-------------------------------------------------------
 //  Returns true if total credits does not exceed 18.
 //-------------------------------------------------------
 private boolean checkCredits(int numCredits) {
   if (numCredits + totalCredits <= MAX_CREDITS) //make sure max   credits not exceeded
   {
    return true; //return a true if still less than 18 credits
   } else {
    return false; //return a false if 18 credit limit is exceeded
   } //end numCredits
  } //checkCredits
  //Method to add a course to the student’s schedule
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  //  Adds a course to the array if total credits does not exceed 18.
  //-------------------------------------------------------
 public void addCourse(String course, int numCredits) {
   if (courseNumber < SIZE) //make sure array is not full. 
   {
    if (checkCredits(numCredits) == true) //if we’re under 18 credits
    {
     //add course
     schedule[courseNumber] = course + ":\t\t" + numCredits + "\tCredits\n";
     //increment number of credits
     totalCredits = totalCredits + numCredits;
     //increment number of courses
     courseNumber = courseNumber + 1;
    } else //oops – can’t do more than 18 credits
    {
     System.out.println("You have exceeded  the maximum allowed credits.");
    } //end checkCredits
   } else //oops – can’t do more than 10 courses
   {
    System.out.println("You have exceeded 10 courses.");
   } //end courseNumber
  } //addCourse
  //Method to display the schedule
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  //  Will only print out the courses added to the array.
  //-------------------------------------------------------
 public void displaySchedule() {
   for (int index = 0; index < courseNumber; index++) {
    System.out.println("Course #" + (index + 1) + " " + schedule[index] + "\n");
   } //end for

  } //end display schedule
 public void searchCourse(String courseName) {
  int index;
  String extract;
  boolean notFound = true;
  index = 0;
  while (index < SIZE) {
   extract = schedule(index).charAt(0, 6);
   if (courseName != extract) {
    index++;
   } else {
    notFound = false;
   }
   if (notFound = true) {
    System.out.println("Course Found");
   } else {
    System.out.println("Course Not Found");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: here is a clean gist : https://gist.github.com/jeorfevre/dd435d610654301dbdfb48c7448313b8

Comment: So what's the actual problem? You've just dumped your homework and a huge mess of code with no specific problem or question. We won't do/finish your homework for you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No one is asking anyone to do anything but provide a little insight @tnw so relax there bud. The problem is clearly stated within the parameters of what the searchCourse method is attempting to do. I am having issues with extracting the course name from the array schedule by using a substring

Answer (score 0):

Search method doesn't look so efficient, maybe something like this:

```
while(index++ < SIZE){
    extract = schedule(index).charAt(0,6);
    if(!(extract == courseName)){ // i belive this returns 0 if true, which would make our if statement false, just use the not operator
        // found the course, do stuff
        return;
    }
}
// if loop ends, then we didn't find the course, do stuff
```